# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence error is showing

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, types, valueerror

I am trying to convert this column in float type from object type but it is giving this error.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['[-0.8783137, 0.05478287, -0.08827557, 0.69203985, 0.06209986]', 
                            '[0.31444644, -0.6546649, 0.7211526, 0.9819127, 0.74042267]']})

df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: [float(i) for i in x.strip('[]').split(',')])
df = df.astype(float)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the "explode" method, which allows to transform each element of a list into a row:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.strip('][').split(', ')) # turn into lists

df = df.explode('col1', ignore_index=True) # expand

df = df.astype("float") # change the data type
```